# Data insertion using array in PHP

Tags: php

I have a php script for conducting online test. while taking test, I am using post method to get the answers in the action page.The answers are passed as an array with question id and the selected option value(true or false/the answers the candidate entered like that).Then I have to insert the answers marked by the candidate in the database. The code is as shown below:

```
$student_id=$_POST['name'];
$survey_id=$_POST['survey_id'];

$store = array();
    if (isset($_POST['question_id'])) {
        foreach ($_POST['question_id'] as $key => $option) {

            $option1 = array_filter($option);
            print_r($option1);


            if (count($option1) > 1) {
                $option2 = implode("^", $option1);
                $store[] = $option2;

            } else {
                $value = $option1;

                $i = implode(null, $option1);

                $store[] = $i;
            }

        }
           print_r($store);
    }

    $t = new DateTime();
    $t->setTimestamp($time = time());
    $t->setTimeZone(new DateTimeZone("Asia/Singapore"));
    $date = $t->format(DateTime::RFC850);

     $SQL = "INSERT INTO answer_table(student_id ,survey_id, ans_1, ans_2, ans_3, ans_4, ans_5, ans_6, ans_7, ans_8, ans_9, ans_10, timestamp) VALUES ('$student_id','$survey_id', '$store[0]', '$store[1]', '$store[2]', '$store[3]', '$store[4]', '$store[5]', '$store[6]', '$store[7]', '$store[8]', '$store[9]', '$date')";

     $result = mysql_query($SQL);
```

If the student answers the test in sequential order(from question number 1 to 10) the code works fine. But when the candidate answers in random manner(first 10 then 5 like that),the table field named,ans_1 will get inserted with answer of question number 10. I need to insert fields with corresponding answers ,(ans_1 with answer of question 1 like that) what ever pattern,the candidate takes test.

Can anyone help me to solve this issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: maybe u can set $store first as $store{"1","2",...}. then when u get answer + question id, u set it like this $store[question_id] = answer

Answer (score 0):

For achieving you goal.you should store question_id with answers or create another table which store question_id and corresponding answers, with id of answer table.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the question id in the `$key` variable, you could use

```
$store[$key] = $option2;
```

instead of

```
$store[] = $option2;
```

With that the first question is the first entry in the array regardless of the order of the answers in the post array.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace  `$store[] = $option2;` with:

```
$store[$_POST['question_id']] = $option2;
```